# Is there a way to get the child class from the parent and check (and use) methods and properties?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a class that will consume classes and create little reports of information. The problem is, even though they all inherit form a base class, these child classes don't have to implement all the sames methods and properties. Just the relevant ones...

I can't cast the classes because at design time I don't which ones will be used... We have a framework and on a job by job basis a developer takes it and implements some job specific code.  They base class has some methods they have to implement (Init, Report, Audit) but then depending on what type of job it is, it will have one or two of a few properties and a method or two.
 So (as my simplistic example below) they might implement Cat, but also need the 2nd class thats simliar to Cat, but different enough to warrant a new class, so create Cat2.
I know it sounds a weird of working, but whilst the the developers are using the framework, they are working with their instantiated classes.

```
class Animal
{
////common stuff
  public 
}

class Cat : Animal
{
  public Name { get; set; }
  public Speak() 
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Meow");
  }
}
class Dog: Animal
{
  public Name { get; set; }
  public Speak() 
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Woof");
  }
}
class Person: Animal
{
  public Title{ get; set; }
  public Name { get; set; }
  public Speak() 
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
  }
}
class Spider: Animal
{
  public Name { get; set; }

}


List<Animal> animals = new List<Animals> {
  new Cat { Name = "Bob" },
  new Dog { Name = "Fido" },
  new Person { Name = "Harry", Title = "Mr" },
  new Spider { Name = "Boris" }
}

foreach (Animal item in animals)
{
  ///now is wishful pseudo code...
  if item has Speak then speak()
  if item has Title then write Title
  if item has Name then write Name
}
```

I just want to loop through the list, if it has a certain property then read it. If it has a certain method, then call it.

Comment: You can create a static List<Animal> and put all instances into the list so you can do you checking.

Comment: You could use something like `if (animal is Cat cat) { /* use cat with all Cat properties and methods */ }`, but that's generally not recommended. And if you use that often, it points to problems in architecture/design. -- that's a new-ish feature (C#7?); before, you could do: `Cat cat = animal as Cat; if (cat != null) { [...] }`. -- see also: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching

Comment: If you "just" want to know if an object has specific properties and/or methods, maybe Reflection might help, but that comes at a rather high cost performancewise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if it has a certain property then read it. If it has a certain method, then call it.

it sounds like each of those features define an `interface`, i.e.

```cs
interface IHazName { string Name {get;} }
interface IHazTitle { string Title {get;} }
interface ICanSpeak { void Speak(); }
...
foreach (Animal item in animals)
{
  if (item is ICanSpeak cs) cs.Speak();
  if (item is IHazTitle ht) Write(ht.Title);
  if (item is IHazName hn) Write(hn.Name);
}
...
class Cat : Animal, IHazName, ICanSpeak
{...}
class Dog : Animal, IHazName, ICanSpeak
{...}
class Person : Animal, IHazName, IHazTitle, ICanSpeak
{...}
class Spider : Animal, IHazName
{...}
```

One particularly nice thing about using interfaces is that you can fudge the names a bit:

```cs
class Dog : Animal, IHazName, ICanSpeak
{
    //...
    public void Bark() { Say("woof"); } // method is called Bark on the public API
    void ICanSpeak.Speak() => Bark(); // but Speak on the ICanSpeak API
}
```

---

Note: the usage here:

```cs
  if (item is ICanSpeak cs) cs.Speak();
```

requires a modern C# compiler; if you're using an older compiler, then:

```cs
  if (item is ICanSpeak) ((ICanSpeak)item).Speak();
```

or:

```cs
  var cs = item as ICanSpeak;
  if (cs != null) cs.Speak();
```

Likewise,

```cs
void ICanSpeak.Speak() => Bark();
```

is the same as, on older compilers,

```cs
void ICanSpeak.Speak() { Bark(); }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in marking it as the correct answer. This worked a treat, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new abstract method, then implement it in child classes.

```
class Animal
{
    abstract Work();
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    public Name;
    public Speak();
    override Work()
    {
        Speak();
        Write Name;
    }
}
class Person: Animal
{
    public Title;
    public Name;
    public Speak();
    override Work()
    {
        Speak();
        Write Title;
        Write Name;
    }
}

foreach (Animal item in animals)
{
    item.Work();
}
```